# 401 error when my javascript app tries to access my google cloud endpoints

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The project is on Google Appengine cloud endpoints framework. 
Python in the backend. 
I'm also using endpoints_proto_datastore (not sure if that makes a difference)

Here is my html file -

```
<html>
<body>

<script>

clientId = 'myclientid-something-something-something.apps.googleusercontent.com'
loginScope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.customer.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic';        
apiKey = 'my-api-key-from-cloud-console';

doSignIn = function() {
  console.log("calling doSignIn");
  gapi.client.init({apiKey: apiKey, clientId: clientId,scope: loginScope}).then(renderSignIn);
}

renderSignIn = function(){
              gapi.signin2.render('my-signin', {
                'scope': loginScope,
                'width': 'inherit',
                'height': 50,
                'longtitle': true,
                'theme': 'light',
                'onsuccess': getOfflineAccess,
                'onfailure': function(){console.log("error")}
             });
};

getOfflineAccess =function(){
  console.log("calling getOfflineAccess");
  gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess({'redirect_uri': 'postmessage'}).then(getApiAuthorization);
}
getApiAuthorization = function(){
  console.log("calling getApiAuthorization");
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId,scope: loginScope, immediate: false},singedInCallback);
};
singedInCallback = function(authResponse) {
    console.log("calling signInCallback");
    gapi.client.endpointsapp.userOfflineAccessCode.insert({'auth_code':authResponse.code})
           .then(   function(){console.log("success");},  
                    function(){console.log("error");}
                ); 
};



init = function() {
  console.log("calling init");
  var apisToLoad;
  var callback = function() {
    if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
      doSignIn();
    }
  }
  apisToLoad = 2; 
  gapi.client.load('endpointsapp','v1',callback,"https://endpointsapp.appspot.com/_ah/api"); //dummy name for app
  gapi.load('client:auth2', callback);
};

</script>
<div id="my-signin"></div>

    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=init"></script>  
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init"></script>  
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Everything goes smooth at first.
I get a google signing button.
I click on it and then all required permissions are granted.
When the actual API hit is made. That gives me a 401.

The response that I get from the API (gapi.client.endpointsapp.userOfflineAccessCode.insert) is :

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 401, 
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global", 
    "message": "Invalid token.", 
    "reason": "required"
   }
  ], 
  "message": "Invalid token."
 }
}
```

When I try the same api endpoint using the google api explorer, if I'm authenticated, everything works, without any issue.

I've been trying to debug this for an entire day but just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok found the issue. Very basic mistake.

According to https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/create_api allowed_client_ids is a required field if the API uses authentication. I was not providing this parameter and expecting the API to be available to all client_ids by default.